# Overflow-X: hidden doesn't work with animation

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm working on a website with animated elements using CSS3. One problem I have is the vertical scrolling bar. So there's an element that is constantly sliding from left to right and back:

```
@keyframes waves {
  0% {left:-50px;}
  50% {left: 0px;}
  100% {left: -50px;}
}
```

So that this works, the object is bigger than the screen size. Now of course the vertical scrolling bar appears. How can I hide that?

I put the element in a container, where I defined `overflow-x: hidden` but somehow it didn't work. Maybe I just did a mistake? What method should I use?

Here's the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/hsdoy3t4/

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's taking default margin of body tag.

Set `margin:0` for body tag.

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}
#home {
 width: 100vw;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}

#object {
 background-image: url('http://www.1000skies.com/800trim.jpg');
 width: calc(100% + 50px);
 height: 158px;
  position: relative;
 -webkit-animation: waves 2s infinite;
    -moz-animation: waves 2s infinite;
    animation: waves 2s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes waves {
  0% {left:-50px;}
  50% {left: 0px;}
  100% {left: -50px;}
}

@-moz-keyframes waves {
  0% {left:-50px;}
  50% {left: 0px;}
  100% {left: -50px;}
}

@keyframes waves {
  0% {left:-50px;}
  50% {left: 0px;}
  100% {left: -50px;}
}
```

```html
<section id="home">
  <div id="object"></div>
</section>
```